I have a view in SQL server that uses both OUTER APPLY as well as a function, I'm having trouble converting this to Snowflake syntax
I tried to recreate the function in snowflake, but from what i've read, functions are resource intensive and generally not recommended in snowflake. So next option is to recreate the function as well as the outerapply logic in Snowflake.
Here is what the function below looks like:
FUNCTION [dbo].[cfn_ConvertMaterialQuantity] (
    @materialID          int,
    @quantity            decimal(18,6),
    @fromUnitOfMeasureID int,
    @toUnitOfMeasureID   int
)
RETURNS decimal(18,6)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (
        SELECT @quantity
            * CASE WHEN @fromUnitOfMeasureID IN ( m.UnitOfMeasureID, @toUnitOfMeasureID   ) THEN 1 ELSE from_muom.QuantityNumerator   END
            * CASE WHEN @toUnitOfMeasureID   IN ( m.UnitOfMeasureID, @fromUnitOfMeasureID ) THEN 1 ELSE to_muom.QuantityDenominator   END
            / CASE WHEN @fromUnitOfMeasureID IN ( m.UnitOfMeasureID, @toUnitOfMeasureID   ) THEN 1 ELSE from_muom.QuantityDenominator END
            / CASE WHEN @toUnitOfMeasureID   IN ( m.UnitOfMeasureID, @fromUnitOfMeasureID ) THEN 1 ELSE to_muom.QuantityNumerator     END
        FROM Material m
        LEFT JOIN MaterialUnitOfMeasure from_muom ON from_muom.MaterialID = m.ID AND from_muom.UnitOfMeasureID = @fromUnitOfMeasureID
        LEFT JOIN MaterialUnitOfMeasure to_muom   ON to_muom.MaterialID   = m.ID AND to_muom.UnitOfMeasureID   = @toUnitOfMeasureID
        WHERE m.ID = @materialID
    );

Here is what the view logic looks like:
SELECT
    c.ID AS CalculationID,
    e.Name AS SourceEquipmentID,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    c.BeginTime,
    c.EndTime,
    c.UpTime,
    c.DownTime,
    c.IdealInput,
    c.ActualInput,
    c.ActualOutput,
    uom_base.Symbol AS BaseUoM,
    dbo.cfn_ConvertMaterialQuantity(m.ID, c.ActualOutput, m.UnitOfMeasureID, uom_Operations.ID) AS ActualOutputOperationsUoM,
    uom_operations.Symbol AS OperationsUoM,
    c.RejectedOutput,
    IIF(s.DefaultCapabilityTypeID = 'COMMITTED', ps.IdealRunRate * (UpTime + DownTime) /3600.0, 0) AS ScheduledOutput,
    c.Failures,
    oreq.ExternalRef AS POnumber,
    CONVERT(DATE, c.BeginTime - ISNULL((SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DateTime) FROM Shift s_first WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID), CAST('6:00' AS DateTime))) AS ProductionDate
FROM       oee.calculation c                          WITH(NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Shift s                                    WITH(NOLOCK) ON s.ID = c.ShiftID AND c.BeginTime > DATEADD(DAY,-31,GETDATE()) AND s.DefaultCapabilityTypeID IN ('COMMITTED', 'AVAILABLE')
INNER JOIN Equipment e                                WITH(NOLOCK) ON e.ID = c.EquipmentID AND e.EquipmentLevelID = 'WORKCENTER'
LEFT  JOIN EquipmentProperty ep                       WITH(NOLOCK) ON e.ID = ep.EquipmentID and ep.EquipmentClassPropertyCode = 'UOM_ON_EQ'
LEFT  JOIN UnitOfMeasure uom_operations               WITH(NOLOCK) ON uom_operations.ID = ep.value
LEFT  JOIN JobOrder jo                                WITH(NOLOCK) ON jo.ID = c.JobOrderID
LEFT  JOIN WorkRequest wr                             WITH(NOLOCK) ON wr.ID = jo.WorkRequestID
LEFT  JOIN OperationsRequest oreq                     WITH(NOLOCK) ON oreq.ID = wr.OperationsRequestID
LEFT  JOIN SegmentRequirementMaterialRequirement srmr WITH(NOLOCK) ON srmr.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID AND srmr.MaterialUseID = 'PRODUCED'
LEFT  JOIN Material m                                 WITH(NOLOCK) ON m.ID = srmr.MaterialID
LEFT  JOIN UnitOfMeasure uom_base                     WITH(NOLOCK) ON uom_base.ID = m.UnitOfMeasureID
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1
        IdealRunRate
    FROM oee.PerformanceSpecification ps WITH(NOLOCK)
    WHERE
        ps.EquipmentID = e.ID AND
        (ps.MaterialID = m.ID
        OR
        (ps.MaterialID IS NULL AND 
            (ps.MaterialClassID = m.PrimaryMaterialClassID OR ps.MaterialClassID IS NULL))
        )
    ORDER BY
        CASE
            WHEN ps.MaterialID = m.ID THEN 2
            WHEN ps.MaterialClassID = m.PrimaryMaterialClassID THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END
    DESC
) ps


I'm not a data engineer nor a particularly sql savy guy, however this is a fun challenge and would make my work much easier.
i am working on writing the sql inside out. There are 4 parameters that get pushed to the function and the function spits out a quantity.
i've tried to start with the function and write that as a CTE, however i am not 100% sure on how to account for the 4 parameters, do i create 4 difference cte's that each provide an input for the function and try to stich it all back together? more importantly, i'm curious how to go about approaching a problem like this. where to start, how to "stitch" everything back together.
below is what i have thus far:
(
    SELECT
        srer.EquipmentID AS EquipmentID,
        m.ExternalRef AS MaterialRef,
        (CAST(SUM(COALESCE(sreg.CorrectedScrapQuantity,sreg.ScrapQuantity)) AS INT) * CASE WHEN m.fromUnitOfMeasureID IN (m.UnitOfMeasureID, toUnitOfMeasureID) THEN 1 ELSE from_muom.QuantityNumerator END
    * CASE WHEN toUnitOfMeasureID IN (m.UnitOfMeasureID, m.fromUnitOfMeasureID) THEN 1 ELSE to_muom.QuantityDenominator END
    / CASE WHEN m.fromUnitOfMeasureID IN (m.UnitOfMeasureID, toUnitOfMeasureID) THEN 1 ELSE from_muom.QuantityDenominator END
    / CASE WHEN toUnitOfMeasureID IN (m.UnitOfMeasureID, m.fromUnitOfMeasureID) THEN 1 ELSE to_muom.QuantityNumerator END) as placeholder,
        sreg.ScrapUnitOfMeasureID as ScrapUnitOfMeasureID,
        sreas.Name AS ScrapReason,
        wr.ID as WorkRequestID,
        DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATE_PART(MINUTE, sreg.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'0', sreg.ScrapTime),'0')) AS DateTime,
        'Manually Registered' AS RegistrationType
    FROM ScrapRegistration sreg                       
    INNER JOIN ScrapReason sreas                       ON sreas.ID = COALESCE(sreg.CorrectedScrapReasonID, sreg.ScrapReasonID)
    INNER JOIN WorkRequest wr                              ON wr.ID = sreg.WorkRequestID
    INNER JOIN SegmentRequirementEquipmentRequirement srer ON srer.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID
    INNER JOIN SegmentRequirementmaterialRequirement srmr  ON srmr.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID AND srmr.MaterialUseID = 'PRODUCED'
    INNER JOIN Material m ON m.ID = srmr.materialID
    LEFT JOIN MaterialUnitOfMeasure from_muom ON from_muom.MaterialID = m.ID AND from_muom.UnitOfMeasureID = m.fromUnitOfMeasureID
LEFT JOIN MaterialUnitOfMeasure to_muom ON to_muom.MaterialID = m.ID AND to_muom.UnitOfMeasureID = toUnitOfMeasureID
    
    GROUP BY DATEADD(MINUTE, 30 * (DATE_PART(MINUTE, sreg.ScrapTime) / 30), DATEADD(HOUR, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'0', sreg.ScrapTime),'0')), srer.EquipmentID, sreas.Name, m.ExternalRef, wr.ID, sreg.ScrapUnitOfMeasureID
)

outside of quantity, i'm having trouble accounting for the other parameters.

well this function is a correlated-sub query, but like all of those it can expressed as a join.
firstly, lets strip out the parts of the outer sql that are not used to "call the function"
this feels like so:
SELECT
    c.ID AS CalculationID,
    e.Name AS SourceEquipmentID,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    --c.BeginTime,
    --c.EndTime,
    --c.UpTime,
    --c.DownTime,
    --c.IdealInput,
    --c.ActualInput,
    --c.ActualOutput,
    --uom_base.Symbol AS BaseUoM,
    dbo.cfn_ConvertMaterialQuantity(m.ID, c.ActualOutput, m.UnitOfMeasureID, uom_Operations.ID) AS ActualOutputOperationsUoM,
    --uom_operations.Symbol AS OperationsUoM,
    --c.RejectedOutput,
    --IIF(s.DefaultCapabilityTypeID = 'COMMITTED', ps.IdealRunRate * (UpTime + DownTime) /3600.0, 0) AS ScheduledOutput,
    --c.Failures,
    --oreq.ExternalRef AS POnumber,
    --CONVERT(DATE, c.BeginTime - ISNULL((SELECT CAST(MIN(s_first.FromTimeOfDay) AS DateTime) FROM Shift s_first WHERE s_first.FromDay = s.FromDay AND s_first.ShiftCalendarID = s.ShiftCalendarID), CAST('6:00' AS DateTime))) AS ProductionDate
FROM oee.calculation as c                          
JOIN Shift as s                                    
    ON s.ID = c.ShiftID 
        AND c.BeginTime > DATEADD(DAY,-31,GETDATE()) 
        AND s.DefaultCapabilityTypeID IN ('COMMITTED', 'AVAILABLE')
JOIN Equipment as e                                
    ON e.ID = c.EquipmentID 
        AND e.EquipmentLevelID = 'WORKCENTER'
LEFT  JOIN EquipmentProperty ep                       
    ON e.ID = ep.EquipmentID 
        and ep.EquipmentClassPropertyCode = 'UOM_ON_EQ'
LEFT  JOIN UnitOfMeasure uom_operations               
    ON uom_operations.ID = ep.value
LEFT  JOIN JobOrder jo                                
    ON jo.ID = c.JobOrderID
LEFT  JOIN WorkRequest wr                             
    ON wr.ID = jo.WorkRequestID
--LEFT  JOIN OperationsRequest oreq                     
--    ON oreq.ID = wr.OperationsRequestID
LEFT  JOIN SegmentRequirementMaterialRequirement srmr 
    ON srmr.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID AND srmr.MaterialUseID = 'PRODUCED'
LEFT  JOIN Material m                                 
    ON m.ID = srmr.MaterialID
--LEFT  JOIN UnitOfMeasure uom_base                     
--    ON uom_base.ID = m.UnitOfMeasureID
--OUTER APPLY
--(
--    SELECT TOP 1
--        IdealRunRate
--    FROM oee.PerformanceSpecification ps WITH(NOLOCK)
--    WHERE
--        ps.EquipmentID = e.ID AND
--        (ps.MaterialID = m.ID
--        OR
--        (ps.MaterialID IS NULL AND 
--            (ps.MaterialClassID = m.PrimaryMaterialClassID OR ps.MaterialClassID IS NULL))
--        )
--    ORDER BY
--        CASE
--            WHEN ps.MaterialID = m.ID THEN 2
--            WHEN ps.MaterialClassID = m.PrimaryMaterialClassID THEN 1
--            ELSE 0
--        END
--    DESC
--) ps  

thus becoming:
SELECT
    c.ID AS CalculationID,
    e.Name AS SourceEquipmentID,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    dbo.cfn_ConvertMaterialQuantity(m.ID, c.ActualOutput, m.UnitOfMeasureID, uom_Operations.ID) AS ActualOutputOperationsUoM
FROM oee.calculation as c                          
JOIN Shift as s                                    
    ON s.ID = c.ShiftID 
        AND c.BeginTime > DATEADD(DAY,-31,GETDATE()) 
        AND s.DefaultCapabilityTypeID IN ('COMMITTED', 'AVAILABLE')
JOIN Equipment as e                                
    ON e.ID = c.EquipmentID 
        AND e.EquipmentLevelID = 'WORKCENTER'
LEFT  JOIN EquipmentProperty ep                       
    ON e.ID = ep.EquipmentID 
        and ep.EquipmentClassPropertyCode = 'UOM_ON_EQ'
LEFT  JOIN UnitOfMeasure uom_operations               
    ON uom_operations.ID = ep.value
LEFT  JOIN JobOrder jo                                
    ON jo.ID = c.JobOrderID
LEFT  JOIN WorkRequest wr                             
    ON wr.ID = jo.WorkRequestID
LEFT  JOIN SegmentRequirementMaterialRequirement srmr 
    ON srmr.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID AND srmr.MaterialUseID = 'PRODUCED'
LEFT  JOIN Material m                                 
    ON m.ID = srmr.MaterialID

The first "table" the function takes from is material, we id equals the value passed, which comes from material table, so the first thing we want on the outside is already there.
first lets rewrite the SQL a little (not totally valid just deconstructing it):
    SELECT 
        @fromUnitOfMeasureID IN ( m.UnitOfMeasureID, @toUnitOfMeasureID   ) as l1,
        @toUnitOfMeasureID   IN ( m.UnitOfMeasureID, @fromUnitOfMeasureID ) as l2,
        iff(l1, 1, fm.QuantityNumerator) as va,
        iff(l2, 1, tm.QuantityDenominator) as vb,
        iff(l1, 1, fm.QuantityDenominator) as vc,
        iff(l2, 1, tm.QuantityNumerator) as vd,
        @quantity * va * vb / vc / vd as result
    FROM Material as m
    LEFT JOIN MaterialUnitOfMeasure as fm 
        ON fm.MaterialID = m.ID 
            AND fm.unitofmeasureid = @fromUnitOfMeasureID
    LEFT JOIN materialunitofmeasure as tm   
        ON tm.materialid = m.ID 
            AND tm.unitofmeasureid = @toUnitOfMeasureID
    WHERE m.ID = @materialID

next the function joins MaterialUnitOfMeasure twice, so lets slap that into the code. replace those to and from with the columns presented to the function:
SELECT
    c.ID AS CalculationID,
    e.Name AS SourceEquipmentID,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    dbo.cfn_ConvertMaterialQuantity(m.ID, c.ActualOutput, m.UnitOfMeasureID, uom_Operations.ID) AS ActualOutputOperationsUoM
FROM oee.calculation as c                          
JOIN Shift as s                                    
    ON s.ID = c.ShiftID 
        AND c.BeginTime > DATEADD(DAY,-31,GETDATE()) 
        AND s.DefaultCapabilityTypeID IN ('COMMITTED', 'AVAILABLE')
JOIN Equipment as e                                
    ON e.ID = c.EquipmentID 
        AND e.EquipmentLevelID = 'WORKCENTER'
LEFT  JOIN EquipmentProperty ep                       
    ON e.ID = ep.EquipmentID 
        and ep.EquipmentClassPropertyCode = 'UOM_ON_EQ'
LEFT  JOIN UnitOfMeasure uom_operations               
    ON uom_operations.ID = ep.value
LEFT  JOIN JobOrder jo                                
    ON jo.ID = c.JobOrderID
LEFT  JOIN WorkRequest wr                             
    ON wr.ID = jo.WorkRequestID
LEFT  JOIN SegmentRequirementMaterialRequirement srmr 
    ON srmr.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID AND srmr.MaterialUseID = 'PRODUCED'
LEFT  JOIN Material m                                 
    ON m.ID = srmr.MaterialID
-- slapping function tables here
LEFT JOIN MaterialUnitOfMeasure as fm 
    ON fm.MaterialID = m.ID 
        AND fm.unitofmeasureid = m.UnitOfMeasureID
LEFT JOIN materialunitofmeasure as tm   
    ON tm.materialid = m.ID 
        AND tm.unitofmeasureid = uom_Operations.ID

and now we can use those two tables to do the math:
SELECT
    c.ID AS CalculationID,
    e.Name AS SourceEquipmentID,
    s.Reference AS Shift,
    --dbo.cfn_ConvertMaterialQuantity(m.ID, c.ActualOutput, m.UnitOfMeasureID, uom_Operations.ID) AS ActualOutputOperationsUoM,
    m.UnitOfMeasureID IN ( m.UnitOfMeasureID, uom_Operations.ID   ) as l1,
    uom_Operations.ID   IN ( m.UnitOfMeasureID, m.UnitOfMeasureID ) as l2,
        iff(l1, 1, fm.QuantityNumerator) as va,
        iff(l2, 1, tm.QuantityDenominator) as vb,
        iff(l1, 1, fm.QuantityDenominator) as vc,
        iff(l2, 1, tm.QuantityNumerator) as vd,
        c.ActualOutput * va * vb / vc / vd as ActualOutputOperationsUoM
FROM oee.calculation as c                          
JOIN Shift as s                                    
    ON s.ID = c.ShiftID 
        AND c.BeginTime > DATEADD(DAY,-31,GETDATE()) 
        AND s.DefaultCapabilityTypeID IN ('COMMITTED', 'AVAILABLE')
JOIN Equipment as e                                
    ON e.ID = c.EquipmentID 
        AND e.EquipmentLevelID = 'WORKCENTER'
LEFT  JOIN EquipmentProperty ep                       
    ON e.ID = ep.EquipmentID 
        and ep.EquipmentClassPropertyCode = 'UOM_ON_EQ'
LEFT  JOIN UnitOfMeasure uom_operations               
    ON uom_operations.ID = ep.value
LEFT  JOIN JobOrder jo                                
    ON jo.ID = c.JobOrderID
LEFT  JOIN WorkRequest wr                             
    ON wr.ID = jo.WorkRequestID
LEFT  JOIN SegmentRequirementMaterialRequirement srmr 
    ON srmr.SegmentRequirementID = wr.SegmentRequirementID AND srmr.MaterialUseID = 'PRODUCED'
LEFT  JOIN Material m                                 
    ON m.ID = srmr.MaterialID
-- slapping function tables here
LEFT JOIN MaterialUnitOfMeasure as fm 
    ON fm.MaterialID = m.ID 
        AND fm.unitofmeasureid = m.UnitOfMeasureID
LEFT JOIN materialunitofmeasure as tm   
    ON tm.materialid = m.ID 
        AND tm.unitofmeasureid = uom_Operations.ID

so now I would change the fake-sql into valid Snowflake SQL, and hey presto, magic

this is wonderful. for my own knowledge, is this approach better than using a CTE? my initial instinct was to make the function a CTE, then tie it back to the body of the query. Also, how is the OUTER APPLY used in this? unless i'm missing something, i don't see that being called

A CTE might make sense to prepare data to join if you were doing processing like aggregation and filters. But the function was just joining. So we can do that on the outside. Yes i striped out code that was not needed to answer the “how to remove function wuestion” feel happy to just blindly add all that code back in.

understood. i'll give it a shot. i know snowflake handles OUTER APPLY differently than it does in sql server. i was having some trouble with that as well, but will give it a try. thank you!
